# Javascript to CSV rows not outputting

Tags: javascript, html, export-to-csv

I am trying to generate csv file from Javascript data input. Each row needs to be from the next cycle of input.

It is not outputting any CSV.

The add and update buttons must both be used per each cycle of input in order to generate a new csv row. For some reason, the ".innnerhtml" does not work when commented in either.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p>My First Paragraph.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
<a href='#' onclick='downloadCSV({ filename: "data-" + ID + ".csv" });'><button title = "download data">⬇️</button></a>
<button onclick="update()">update</button>
<button onclick="add()">add</button>
<script>
function add() {
var ID = prompt("Please enter your email address (One per user)");
var HR = prompt("Please enter your HeartRate");
var TIME = prompt("please enter the time");
var PREDICTION = prompt("Please enter your HR prediction")
var biodata = [
        {
            ID: ID,
            HR: "65",
            TIME: "8",
            PREDICTION: "68",
            }
    ];
  }

function update() {
var row = {};
row[ID] = biodata.ID;
row[HR] = biodata.HR;
row[TIME] = biodata.TIME;
row[PREDICTION] = biodata.PREDICTION;
biodata.push(row);
//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = biodata;
}

function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
    var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

    data = args.data || null;
    if (data == null || !data.length) {
        return null;
    }

    columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
    lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

    keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

    result = '';
    result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
    result += lineDelimiter;

    data.forEach(function(item) {
        ctr = 0;
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
            if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

            result += item[key];
            ctr++;
        });
        result += lineDelimiter;
    });

    return result;
}

function downloadCSV(args) {
    var data, filename, link;

    var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
        data: biodata
    });
    if (csv == null) return;

    filename = args.filename || "data-" + ID + ".csv"; //changed to double qoutes.

    if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
        csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
    }
    data = encodeURI(csv);

    link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', data);
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.click();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplified solution:

JS:

```
var USER = prompt("Please enter your initials");
var TIME = "TIME";
var BPM = "BPM";
var PRED = "PRED";
var value = "0";
var data = [
   [USER, TIME, BPM, PRED]
];
function download_csv() {
    var csv = 'USER,TIME,BPM,PRED\n';
    data.forEach(function(row) {
            csv += row.join(',');
            csv += "\n";
    });

    console.log(csv);
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    filename = USER + "-biodata.csv";
    hiddenElement.download = filename;
    hiddenElement.click();
}

function appendcsv() {

  data.push([USER, TIME, BPM, PRED]);
//adds new row of data from updated values from loop.
}
```

HTML:

```
<button title = "download bio data" onclick="download_csv()">EXPORT</button></a>
<button title = "add row of data" onclick="appendcsv()">Add row</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ID` and `biodata` variables are declared in the scope of the `add()` function but are being referenced inline in your HTML and in the `downloadCSV()` function. One possible solution would be to declare these as global variables:

```
<script>
    var ID;
    var biodata;

    function add() {
        ID = prompt("Please enter your email address (One per user)");
        var HR = prompt("Please enter your HeartRate");
        var TIME = prompt("please enter the time");
        var PREDICTION = prompt("Please enter your HR prediction")
        biodata = [
        ...
```

Instead of

```
<script>

    function add() {
        var ID = prompt("Please enter your email address (One per user)");
        var HR = prompt("Please enter your HeartRate");
        var TIME = prompt("please enter the time");
        var PREDICTION = prompt("Please enter your HR prediction")
        var biodata = [
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you. This only partially fixes the script though. It can only make a single-row csv with your modifications. The script is supposed to allow multiple rows with the add button.